Pilas en arreglos
estoy realizando el siguiente programa para la solución del problema que mencionaré a continuación:
Descripción
Como sabes, muy pocas páginas de internet se ven igual usando exploradores diferentes. Una herramienta muy importante para prevenir incompatibilidades es la validación de código escrito en lenguajes de marcado y aunque para páginas web esto se puede complicar bastante, tu labor será más sencilla.
Para nuestros fines, una etiqueta de apertura es un identificador compuesto por caracteres alfanuméricos y guiones bajos (aunque por regla el primer carácter del identificador no puede ser un número) y su etiqueta de cierre será el mismo identificador precedido por una /. Puede haber un número arbitrario de espacios en blanco entre etiquetas. Las etiquetas tienen una posición numerada de forma consecutiva a partir del 1.
El documento tiene una profundidad inicial de 0, cada vez que se encuentra una etiqueta de apertura la profundidad aumenta en 1 y cada vez que se encuentra una de cierre la profundidad disminuye en 1. Un documento de marcado está mal formado si:

Tiene etiquetas inválidas (123_gato es inválida pues inicia en número).

Alguna etiqueta de apertura no tiene su cierre o viceversa.

El cierre de una etiqueta externa ocurre antes del cierre de una etiqueta interna (por ejemplo aa bb /bb /aa es correcto pero aa bb /aa /bb no lo es).


Entrada
Una línea de texto de no más de 10,000 caracteres. Puedes suponer que la longitud de las etiquetas contenidas dentro del texto no superará los 100 caracteres cada una.
Salida
Una letra mayúscula seguida de un número entero. En el caso de que el documento esté bien formado entonces la letra debe ser V y el número entero debe ser la profundidad máxima. En el caso de que el documento esté mal formado entonces la letra debe ser I y el número entero deberá ser la posición de la primera etiqueta que provoque un error.
Entiendo que una pila es una estructura de datos que sigue el principio de LIFO (Last In, First Out), lo que significa que el último elemento que se inserta es el primero en ser eliminado. En este caso, utilice una pila para rastrear las etiquetas de apertura encontradas en el texto, lo que permite verificar la validez de las etiquetas de cierre.
El problema es en la salidas:

Mis salidas son las siguientes:





Mi código es el siguiente:
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

// Función para verificar si una etiqueta es válida
bool esEtiquetaValida(const string& etiqueta) {
    // Verifica si la etiqueta es válida
    if (!isalpha(etiqueta[0])) // El primer carácter no es alfabético
        return false;
    for (char c : etiqueta) {
        if (!isalnum(c) && c != '_') // Los caracteres no son alfanuméricos ni guiones bajos
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// Función principal
int main() {
    string texto;
    getline(cin, texto); // Lee la línea de texto

    istringstream iss(texto); // Crea un flujo de entrada stringstream con el texto
    string palabra; // Variable para almacenar cada palabra del texto
    int profundidad = 0; // Variable para almacenar la profundidad actual del documento
    int posicionError = 0; // Variable para almacenar la posición del primer error

    // Itera sobre cada palabra del texto
    while (iss >> palabra) {
        if (palabra[0] == '<') {
            // Etiqueta de apertura
            string etiqueta = palabra.substr(1); // Obtiene la etiqueta sin el carácter '<'
            if (!esEtiquetaValida(etiqueta)) {
                // Etiqueta no válida
                cout << "I " << posicionError << endl;
                return 0; // Sale del programa
            }
            ++profundidad; // Aumenta la profundidad
        } else if (palabra[0] == '/') {
            // Etiqueta de cierre
            string etiqueta = palabra.substr(1); // Obtiene la etiqueta sin el carácter '/'
            if (profundidad == 0 || etiqueta != palabra.substr(1)) {
                // Etiqueta de cierre sin etiqueta de apertura correspondiente o incorrecta
                cout << "I " << posicionError << endl;
                return 0; // Sale del programa
            }
            --profundidad; // Disminuye la profundidad
        }
        ++posicionError; // Aumenta la posición del error
    }

    // Verifica si el documento está bien formado o no
    if (profundidad == 0) {
        // Documento bien formado
        cout << "V " << profundidad << endl;
    } else {
        // Documento mal formado
        cout << "I " << posicionError << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

Puede ser que esta detectando un error al encontrar una etiqueta de cierre que no coincide, no estoy muy seguro de como poder solucionarlo, les agradecería muchos sus consejos para poder encontrar la solución.

El problema es que no almacenas el nombre de la etiqueta. El profesor te propone usar una pila para hacerlo.

Una pila es un espacio de memoria que se usa para guardar algo, en ese espacio solo se pueden apilar cosas por lo que para sacar algo debes comenzar sacando el ultimo objeto que apilaste.

Tienes varios problemas en el código:

Las etiquetas pueden empezar por "_", por lo que:
if (!isalpha(etiqueta[0]))

debería ser en todo caso:
if (!isalpha(etiqueta[0]) && etiqueta[0] != '_')


No dice que las etiquetas de apertura empiecen por "<".

Debes incrementar el contador posicionError antes de imprimir, ya que indica la posición de la etiqueta incorrecta actual.

Te piden la profundidad máxima alcanzada, en tu caso profundidad registra le profundidad final, que será cero si el documento está bien formado.

Tu código solo funcionaría si cada etiqueta de apertura es seguida por su cierre. No usas una pila como mencionas para almacenar las etiquetas abiertas pendientes de ser cerradas. La idea básica es:

Si es una etiqueta de apertura:

Si no es válida, retornar imprimiendo el error.
Si es válida, agregarla a la pila.


Si es una etiqueta de cierre:

Si no es válida, retornar imprimiendo el error.
Si es válida:

Si coincide con la última etiqueta agregada a la pila, extraerla de la pila y continuar.
Si no coincide, se está intentando cerrar una etiqueta superior o no abierta previamente. Terminar e imprimir el error.




Si se terminan de procesar las etiquetas sin error, comprobar si la pila está vacía:

Si lo está el documento es correcto.
Si no lo está, han quedado etiquetas por cerrar.





En definitiva, usando std::stack, puedes hacer algo como:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>


bool esEtiquetaValida(const std::string& etiqueta) {
    if (!isalpha(etiqueta[0]) && etiqueta[0] != '_')
        return false;
    for (char c: etiqueta) {
        if (!isalnum(c) && c != '_')
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::stack<std::string> tags;
    std::string texto;
    getline(std::cin, texto);

    std::istringstream iss(texto);
    std::string tag;
    size_t profundidad_max = 0;
    int posicion_error = 0;

    while (iss >> tag) {
        ++posicion_error;

        if (tag[0] != '/') {
            if (!esEtiquetaValida(tag)) {
                std::cout << "I " << posicion_error << std::endl;
                return 0;
            }
            tags.push(tag);
            profundidad_max = std::max(profundidad_max, tags.size());

        } else {
            if (tags.empty() || tag.substr(1) != tags.top()) {
                std::cout << "I " << posicion_error << std::endl;
                return 0;
            }
            tags.pop();
        }
    }

    if (tags.empty()) {
        std::cout << "V " << profundidad_max << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "I " << posicion_error + 1 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


"No dice que las etiquetas...", es html por lo que es probable que empiece así. Pero tambien las entradas que pone el usuario me hace dudar de esto.

@DABL03 me dejaste con la duda existencial, por lo que me fui a ver si encontraba el problema por ahí, pegando "Tiene etiquetas inválidas (123_gato es inválida pues inicia en número)." en el buscador... :),  tuve suerte, es éste. Mirando las entradas de prueba, parece que efectivamente no se usan paréntesis angulares. Además te deja probar el código sobre los test iniciales y agregar algunos propios sin registrarse..., así de paso he podido probar el código, luego explotará si se sube por alguna otra razón, pero los test los pasa al menos...

Ha, pense que lo saco de una tarea. Gracias por la info.

Necesitas una pila para conocer las etiquetas que hay abiertas.
El código es más simple de lo que crees. Debes:

Verificar si el nombre es válido.
Si es una etiqueta de apertura, la agregas a la pila. Si es de cierre, verificas que corresponda a la última etiqueta de apertura y la sacas de la pila.
Verificar que no hayan quedado etiquetas abiertas.

Así queda:
int main() {
    stack<string> etiquetas;
    
    string texto;
    getline(cin, texto); // Lee la línea de texto

    istringstream iss(texto); // Crea un flujo de entrada stringstream con el texto
    string palabra; // Variable para almacenar cada palabra del texto

    int profundidadMaxima = 0;
    int nEtiqueta = 1;
    bool error = false;

    // Itera sobre cada palabra del texto
    while (iss >> palabra) {
        bool cierre = palabra[0] == '/';
        string nombre = cierre ? palabra.substr(1) : palabra;

        if (!esEtiquetaValida(nombre)){
            error = true; break;
        }
        
        if (!cierre){
            etiquetas.push(nombre);
            if (etiquetas.size() > profundidadMaxima)
                profundidadMaxima = profundidad;
        }
        else if (!etiquetas.empty() && cierre && nombre == etiquetas.top()) {
            etiquetas.pop();
        }
        else {
            error = true; break;
        }

        ++nEtiqueta;
    }

    if (!error && etiquetas.empty()){
        // Documento bien formado
        cout << "V " << profundidadMaxima << endl;
    } else {
        // Documento mal formado
        cout << "I " << nEtiqueta << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


Falto agregar el encabezado necesario: #include 

El problema es que no almacenas el nombre de la etiqueta y no lo usas para comparar con el nombre de cierre. El profesor te propone usar una pila para hacerlo, Una pila es un espacio de memoria que se usa para guardar algo, en ese espacio solo se pueden apilar cosas por lo que para sacar algo debes comenzar sacando el ultimo objeto que apilaste. Dicho esto, creemos una:
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef struct stack{
  string value;//La cadena a ingresar.
  stack* previous_item;
};

Ya con la estructura de nuestra pila creada, debemos hacer metodo para insertar y sacar:
//Insertar elementos.
void push(stack* s,string value){
  //El item actual ahora pasa a ser el anterior.
  stack* old_stack=new stack;
  old_stack->value=s->value;
  old_stack->previous_item=s->previous_item;
  
  //Apilamos el item
  s->value=value;
  s->previous_item=old_stack;
}
//Sacar elementos.
string pop(stack* s){
  //Obtenemos el item actual.
  static string value;
  value=s->value;

  if (s->previous_item==NULL)//No hay mas item que sacar.
    return value;
  
  //Hacemos el item anterior el actual y liberamos el anterior.
  stack now={s->previous_item->value,s->previous_item->previous_item};
  delete s->previous_item;//Liberamos la memoria que ocupa la cima de la pila.
  
  //Quitamo el item en la cima.
  s->value=now.value;
  s->previous_item=now.previous_item;

  return value;//Retornamos lo que valia la pila.
  
}

Otro error que veo, es que no guarda el valor mas alto de anidación que llegaran las etiquetas.
Ya sabiendo como funciona la pila y un posible error, recomiendo usar una clase ya existente de C++ llamada stack (Si, como las respuestas anteriores), del encabezado :
#include <stack>
//Tus encabezados ...
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string texto;
    getline(cin, texto);

    istringstream iss(texto);//Crea un flujo de entrada stringstream con el texto
    string palabra;
    stack<string> tags;
    int profundidad = 0;//Punto de anidación de las etiquetas.
    //int posicionError = 0;//No es necesario, con profundidad basta.
    unsigned int max_nesting=0;

    // Itera sobre cada palabra del texto
    while (iss >> palabra) {
        if (palabra[0] == '<') {
            // Etiqueta de apertura
            string etiqueta = palabra.substr(1); //Eliminamos el '<'
            if (!esEtiquetaValida(etiqueta)) {
                // Etiqueta no válida
                cout << "I " << posicionError << endl;
                return 0; //END main:)
            }
            tags.push(etiqueta);
            profundidad++;
            if (profundidad>max_nesting)max_nesting=profundidad;//Vemos si hay uno mayor.
        } else if (palabra[0] == '/') {// Etiqueta de cierre
            string etiqueta = palabra.substr(1);//Quitamos el '/'
            
            if (profundidad == 0 || etiqueta != tags.top()) {
                // Etiqueta de cierre sin etiqueta de apertura correspondiente o incorrecta
                cout << "I " << profundidad << endl;
                return 0; //Finish:)
            }
            tags.pop();
            profundidad--;
        }
    }

    // Verifica si el documento está bien formado o no
    if (profundidad == 0) {// Documento bien formado
        cout << "V " << max_nesting << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "I " << profundidad << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


Perdon si consigues un error de sintaxis, no me dio tiempo de provarlo
